# What's written on Q's cup in Skyfall?

Tags: james-bond, props, skyfall

Saw Skyfall over the weekend and was just wondering what's written on the side and bottom of Q's cup?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I didn't watch Skyfall, but some of googling gives me this picture which says its Q<sub>10</sub>.

[image]

Its part of Wild and Wolf's Scrabble mug collection.

Each ceramic mug features one Scrabble letter on the front and the official Scrabble letter distribution chart on the back.[(Source)](http://www.quora.com/Skyfall-2012-movie/Whats-on-Qs-cup-in-Skyfall-2012)

Available for purchase on [ebay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Scrabble-Mugs-by-Wild-Wolf-A-Z-Free-Delivery-/290538632483), [amazon](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Wild-Wolf-Scrabble-Mug-Q/dp/B0041RRC7C) and [wildandwolf.com](http://usa.wildandwolf.com/home_interior/mugs3/scrabble_mug_q.htm).

Here is images for the back of cup you are talking about

[image]

And here its detailed look

[image]

Answer (score 5):

It is a Scrabble mug.  The opposite face is the letter distribution (the number of tiles per letter in the classic Scrabble set).  The bottom is the Scrabble logo.

They are available for purchase [here](http://www.google.com/imgres?hl=en&sa=X&tbo=d&tbm=isch&tbnid=EVcQNVWf4a-0UM%3a&imgrefurl=http://www.incrediblethings.com/food/scrabble-without-coffee-is-like-q-without-a-u/&docid=B6agOmhsvOVyFM&imgurl=http://www.incrediblethings.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/10/Scrabble-Coffee-Mugs-1.jpg&w=570&h=372&ei=tjm1UN3XCbTE0AGYtoHIAg&zoom=1&iact=rc&dur=431&sig=109866874620237023219&page=1&tbnh=134&tbnw=200&start=0&ndsp=22&ved=1t:429,r:0,s:0,i:88&tx=58&ty=25&biw=1366&bih=636)